# Can hardware RAID-1 be enabled on an existing Ubuntu 18.04 system?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, ubuntu-18.04, raid-1

I have an ASUS Ubuntu 18.04 system running on an M.2 drive as /dev/nvme1n1.  I have added an identical M.2 drive and would like to enable hardware RAID-1 (motherboard supports it).  The blank M.2 drive is showing in my system as /dev/nvme0n1.  However, when I boot using a live CD, the drives are detected in the opposite order.

After enabling RAID-1, what changes to grub, fstab, etc. will be required to get the system to boot?  i.e. Will the system still see the RAID-1 as /dev/nvme0n1 and /dev/nvme1n1 or some other device?

Would the RAID-1 array appear as a different device and mess up the boot of the already installed system. What would be the process to ensure that the system will boot on the newly created array that contains the old bootable system?

Comment: If can be done _if_ your motherboard supports it; some do, some don't. Please consult your motherboard manual.

Comment: Yes, motherboard supports it.  To clarify, I am wondering what would happen at boot time with the drive assignments /dev/nvme0n1 and /dev/nvme1n1.  Would the RAID-1 array appear as a different device and mess up the boot of the already installed system.  What would be the process to ensure that the system will boot on the newly created array that contains the old bootable system?

Comment: Clarify by clicking [edit] and putting that into the Question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: The question is asking about the effect on booting Ubuntu after enabling hardware RAID-1, not whether or not it is possible as a motherboard feature.